# SwiftUI list background color is not completely changing

Tags: list, swiftui

There is list SwiftUI. I am trying to give a dark gray background for the whole screen but there are parts of list which are not changing to dark gray and the show up as pitch black. Here is the code to create list

```
 List{
            ForEach(array_Of_Identifiable_structs) { $item in
                 ...RowStruct(varForIdentifiable_struct: $item)
                                    .background(Color.uiColor(.backgroundColor))
            }
  }
               
  .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
  .background(Color.uiColor(.backgroundColor))
```

Also in ...someRowStruct for row, I have changed the background. Here is the body-

```
var body: some View {
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                HStack {
                    .Text(....)
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 0, bottom: 10, trailing:0))
                }  
                .background(Color.uiColor(.backgroundColor))
             }
             .background(Color.uiColor(.backgroundColor))
}
```

Here is screenshot, Just check the row at both the ends of row, it is pitch black, need to make it dark gray -

[image]

Any suggestion is welcome! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `ForEach` View isn't a for loop it doesn't support indices (it will crash when the last index is removed and you attempt to look up the array using an index doesn't exist) you have to supply an array of `Identifiable` structs so it can work with the values instead. You just have to make an item that has the data and the row colour already so you don't have to look it up.

Comment: I am supplying array of Identifiable structs to "For each" and this code is woking fine.  It brings up all the rows fine. I have changed the background color  on each row and it does take affect in in-between gaps. But sides of the row are left.

List{
            ForEach(asomerray.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                 ...someRowStruct(someDStruct: $data.somestruct[index])
                                    .background(Color.uiColor(.backgroundColor))
            }
  }

Comment: `ForEach(asomerray.indices)` will crash when there is a change near the end of the array, it has to be `ForEach(asomerray)`

Comment: The only reason I used it this way was to use binding var on each row.  I have a requirement where data on row can be changed and has to be saved in @EnvironmentObject data.

Comment: you can use `ForEach($asomerray) { $item in` or `ForEach($store.items) { $item in` to get a binding

Comment: Thanks @malhal for the suggestion. Updated the code and it works fine.  But the original issue with row color still is there. The background color does not fill the row completely and leaves the ends.
Thanks again.